# AWS API Gateway Custom Authorizer giving exception

Tags: lambda, authorization, jwt, aws-api-gateway

I have to create custom authorization using AWS API Gateway and Lambda.

I followed all the step mention on [offical doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html#api-gateway-custom-authorizer-output). But at the end gateway is giving `Unauthorized`

Below are the steps I followed.

1) Created lambda function (according to the blueprint available on [github](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints/blob/master/blueprints/nodejs/index.js)). It will return policyDocument in the proper format. This has been
   tested with following test data - 

`{
      "type": "TOKEN",
      "methodArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxx:fgdfgdfg/null/GET/",
      "authorizationToken": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjEyMzQ1Njc4OTAiLCJuYW1lIjoiSm9obiBEb2UiLCJhZG1pbiI6dHJ1ZX0.x8R6LPytDMrPuUBY71skyLBUrkme86DhioN3L7LY_-0"
   }`

2) Create an API. Choose 'Create Method' -> Get -> Selet Integration type as 'Lambda Function' -> Choose region and lambda function name
   that has been created in the previous step.

- [Refer this.](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1507621693.png)
- [Integration request](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1507621904.png)
- [Integration response](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1507621993.png)

3) Click on Authorizers (on left panel) -> Create New Authorizer -> Given Authorizer Name -> Choose Lambda as a type -> Choose Lambda function ->
   Lambda execution role is the arn with basix execution role policy -> payload as Token -> Token Source is 'method.request.header.Authorization' -> caching is disable.

[Refer this](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1507622088.png)

4) Test the Authorizer and it returns proper policy

5) I have deployed the API

6) Trying to invoke URL with Postman with 'Authorization: Bearer '. And output is {
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Since you're using Postman, can you just post the Postman code (Go to "code" then choose either HTTP or cURL) in your question as well?

Comment: Did you really use `Header: Bearer` as one of your headers or is that just a typo? That's why I'm suggesting you post what you have in your Postman.

Comment: @dashmug it's typo. I have used `Authorization: Bearer <token>` in postman

Comment: As requested, show your postman code so we see your payload.

Comment: @dashmug, I got the solution I will post the solution soon. I misunderstood the working of API Gateway with Authorizer. AWS docs related to api gateway is not good. I have wasted so many days in that. Anyway thanks!

Comment: Hi Sanket, what was the solution? How can we improve the documentation?

Comment: Hi Jack, I have added my comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, AWS is great. I've been playing with API Gateway since month now. The documentation for API Gateway really need some update. I experienced that working with API Gateway required a lot of trial and error method. It appears that the documentation (specifically Custom Authorizer for API Gateway) has been written by assuming that the devs knows the things that required to build the authorizer for API Gateway.

I don't know if I missed something or it is too complex to understand the documentation of custom authorizer. After investigating (considerable amount of time) I figured out that the exact working of it. I'll try to explain it below for somebody who may find this useful.

There is really simple concept of custom authorizer. When we create authorizer (token based or request based) then the request that comes from client will first execute authorizer (Lambda function) and after that, if request is allowed, API Gateway will forward the request to the upstream (or Endpoint URL). That's it! There is no more confusion here.

This is what I was expecting from the documentation. There are video's available out there but they need to updated because of the newly awesome features that has been added.(Like Request based authorizer)

I'm building a POC by comparing AWS API Gateway with Kong API Gateway. Trust me, I need only one-two days to complete the setup the Kong and 8-10 days for AWS API Gateway. Anyway Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your token source is "Authorization" yet in your payload you send it in "AuthorizationToken".

Comment: In my question, if you see screencast in my questio (http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1507621904.png)  

I have mapping "Authorization" to the "authorizationToken" in body mapping template. So ultimately it's going to send "authorizationToken" only.